# 301 htaccess redirect for a pattern

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to 301 redirect to all my URLs who have a specific pattern.

Old URLs are like

```
http://www.example.in/1231/ask-meaning-in-hindi
http://www.example.in/1233/blow-meaning-in-hindi
http://www.example.in/1235/beyond-meaning-in-hindi
```

I want to redirect them to a pattern like this:

```
http://www.example.in/1231/ask
http://www.example.in/1233/blow
http://www.example.in/1235/beyond
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+/[^-]+)-.+$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: I made an edit, please try now.